# Application module missing in python

Tags: python

I was trying to run example program [first.py in ns3](http://www.nsnam.org/docs/manual/html/python.html#an-example-python-script-that-runs-ns3).

It was giving missing `ns.application error.`

How can I resolve the problem?
I am new to ns3.

Comment: I would say you need to install ns

Comment: in your terminal type python, then try import ns. If that work, try the import statements you see on the page